# How to convert an array of file names to JSON and add a key

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, fs

I'm setting up a new web page that shows all of the files in a folder.  How can I convert an array of document names to JSON?

To do this, I know I need a JSON object to send from the server to the front end.  I currently have an array of the document names but I don't know how to convert this to JSON and add a key to each of the values.  I've tried using JSON.stringify() and numerous other ways given by users here, to no avail.

```
let docs = [];
    fs.readdir(../../docs', function(err, docs) {
        let json = JSON.stringify(docs);
        res.send(json);
```

I expect the output to be

```
[
   {
      "catalogName": "doc.pdf"
   },
   {
      "catalogName": "doc2.pdf"
   }
]
```

I am currently getting
`["doc.pdf", "doc2.pdf"]`

Comment: You are confusing the term JSON with the concept of an Object. JSON is simply a string that follows a specific format. A simple Object is a data structure that contains `key:value` pairs. Your sample output is an Object. That being the case, they keys `catalogName` do not need to be quoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let json = JSON.stringify(docs.map((doc) => { 
  return {
    catalogueName: doc
  };
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could map the value as object.

```js
var array = ["doc.pdf", "doc2.pdf"],
    result = array.map(catalogName => ({ catalogName }));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

```
fs.readdir('.', function(err, docs) {
   const docMap = docs.reduce((docMap,doc)=>{
        return docMap.concat({"catalogName":doc})
    },[])
    console.log(docMap)
});
```

It generates output like

```
[ { catalogName: 'node_modules' },
  { catalogName: 'package.json' },
  { catalogName: 'README.md' },
  { catalogName: 'test.js' } ]
```

Play with this code, you might need to change the directory! Have fun.